# Matrices Further Mathematics A-Level

Tags: matrices

[image]

[image]

I can solve the first part but after that, I'm not sure what to do. How do I relate what I need to show with the original matrix of A and subsequently prove the rest of the question?

Comment: Ahhhh good old times , still remember doing this when I was preparing for My CIE exam :D

Comment: @ying What textbook is this from?

Comment: @seeker This is a past year question. May/June 2013 (9231/13)

Comment: @TheArtist Haha, can't wait to be saying the same thing when I end.

Comment: @Ying good luck ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second part :

The rank of $A$ is $3$, the kernel of $A$ is $\lambda(1,1,1,1)$ with $\lambda \in \mathbb R$

Next A$\pmatrix{p\\q\\r\\0}=\pmatrix{p-q-r\\2p-q-4r\\3p-3q-2r\\5p-4q-6r}$ , so if
 the right side of this equation is dentoed with $b$, then $\pmatrix{p\\q\\r\\0}$ is a special solution of the equation $Ax=b$. The general solution is the special solution plus the general solution of $Ax=0$, which is the kernel of A.

So, every solution must be of the given form.

Third part :

$\pmatrix{1&-1&-1\\2&-1&-4\\3&-3&-2\\5&-4&-6}$ has rank $3$. The first three rows
 produce rank $3$, so solve the equation

$\pmatrix{1&-1&-1\\2&-1&-4\\3&-3&-2}x=\pmatrix{3\\7\\8}$

The solution is $\pmatrix{1\\-1\\-1}$ , which indeed solves the equation, so
$p=1,q=-1;r=-1$

Comment: Hint to the last part : The general solution is $\pmatrix{1+\lambda \\ -1+\lambda \\ -1+\lambda \\ \lambda}$. The result is $\lambda=\frac{1}{4}$